# Delete almost duplicates in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, data-cleaning

I have a table where strings 1 and 2 are almost duplicate - they have the same values but in reverse order. How can I delete these duplicates?

```
+--------+-------+
| COL_1  | COL_@ |
+--------+-------+
| a1     | b1    |
| b1     | a1    | <- same as 1stline but in reversed order, needs to be removed
| a2     | b2    |   
| a3     | b3    |
| b3     | a3    |<-- also is duplicate of string above, one of these 2str need                        
+--------+-------+     to be removed

expected result:
+--------+-------+
| COL_1  | COL_@ |
+--------+-------+
| b1     | a1    | 
| a2     | b2    |   
| a3     | b3    |                   
+--------+-------+

or
+--------+-------+
| COL_1  | COL_@ |
+--------+-------+
| a1     | b1    |
| a2     | b2    |   
| a3     | b3    |                    
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What is your end_result?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Added an explanation of end result in my question

Comment: How come you want to keep (a1, b1) instead of (b1, a1)? Remember that the rows have no implicit order.

Comment: Add the rows (a4, b4) and (a4, b4) to your sample data, and describe the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this :

```
DELETE(
    select e.COL_@, f.COL_1
    from example as e
    join example as f on e.COL_@ = f.COL_1 and e.COL_@ < f.COL_1 )
```

Comment: The syntax is off. Oracle doesn't accept `AS` for table qualifiers and I doubt very much that it can delete from a view where two tables are joined (no matter that it's a self join here). Which of the two joined rows do you expect it to delete?

Comment: Doesn't matter, actually.

Comment: @Katya: What is this supposed to mean? It doesn't matter whether your DBMS is able to run the SQL statement or not? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, you got me wrong. This was the answer on your question which of rows should be deleted :) In my case, there is no difference which row will be saved in DB

Comment: @Katya: Haha, okay. That was a rhetorical question. I wanted to point out that Oracle would have no means to know which rows to delete with such a syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If col_1 and col_@ cannot be null, you can use `LEAST`and `GREATEST` to keep one row per combination:

```
delete from tbl
where rowid not in
(
  select min(rowid) -- one rowid per combination to keep
  from tbl
  group by least(col_1, col_@), greatest(col_1, col_@)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bit complicated to achieve it with a delete query.
Maybe it is OK for you to have such a select query first:

```
select A,B from (
                    select A,
                           B,
                           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ORA_HASH(A) * ORA_HASH(B) ORDER BY A) as RANK
                    FROM <your_table_name>
) where RANK = 1;
```

You could save the result of this query as a new table with `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...`
And then you simply DROP your old table.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem so complicated:

```
delete t
   where not (col1 < col2 or
              not exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.col1 = t.col2 and
                                t2.col2 = t.col1
                         )
             );
```

Or:

```
delete t
   where col1 > col2 and
         exists (select 1
                 from t t2
                 where t2.col1 = t.col2 and
                       t2.col2 = t.col1
             );
```

Comment: It seems it is ;-) `delete t where col1 < col2 or ...` may delete a lot of rows that don't even have a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

```
DELETE FROM T
  WHERE (COL_1, "COL_@") IN (SELECT COL_1, "COL_@"
                             FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, t1.COL_1, t1."COL_@"
                                     FROM T t1
                                     INNER JOIN T t2
                                       ON t2."COL_@" = t1.COL_1 AND
                                          t2.COL_1 = t1."COL_@")
                             WHERE RN / 2 <> TRUNC(RN / 2));
```

Note that `COL_@` must be quoted in Oracle as `@` is not a legal character in an unquoted identifier.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dadfbccbe170600fc911477d00acc80)